# Set a minimum execution time for onMouseDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have the following popup window in my application which utilizes Bootstrap Tabs:

[image]

The *Feedback* tab has several sub-tabs and I have added functionality so that you can scroll between the overflowing sub-tabs (left and right). Here's how I've implemented that functionality (ReactJS):

```
this.feedbackScrollInterval = -1;    

_feedbackScroll = (id) => {
  let obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.feedbackNav);
  let scrollWidth = obj.firstChild.scrollWidth;
  let offsetWidth = obj.firstChild.offsetWidth;
  if(this.feedbackScrollInterval==-1) {
    this.feedbackScrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
      if(id==1) {
        obj.firstChild.scrollLeft -= 5;
      } else {
        obj.firstChild.scrollLeft += 5;
      }
    }, 15);
  }
}

_clearFeedbackScroll = () => {
  clearInterval(this.feedbackScrollInterval);
  this.feedbackScrollInterval = -1;
}
```

and the markup for the buttons:

```
<Button onMouseDown={this._feedbackScroll.bind(this, 1)} onMouseUp={this._clearFeedbackScroll}><Glyphicon glyph="chevron-left"></Glyphicon></Button>
<Button onMouseDown={this._feedbackScroll.bind(this, 2)} onMouseUp={this._clearFeedbackScroll}><Glyphicon glyph="chevron-right"></Glyphicon></Button>
```

The above *works as intended*, but **I want to add a minimum scroll time**. For example, if I want a minimum scroll time of `250ms` and the `mouseUp` event triggers after `150ms`, I want the scroll to continue for another `100ms`, until the minimum has been met.

How can this be implemented? (no jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a record of the time each time you start the scroll action.

```
this.scrollStarted = Date.now();
```

Then when the scroll finishes, check the duration.

```
let scrollFinished = Date.now();
let duration = scrollFinished - this.scrollStarted;
```

If the duration is greater than your threshold (`250`), then you can clear the interval. Otherwise, use `setTimeout` to appropriately delay the cancellation.

```
if(duration > 250) {
  // go ahead and cancel the scroll
} else {
  setTimeout(this._clearFeedbackScroll, 250 - duration);
}
```

Comment: The problem I see with this implementation is that these variables would be in the global scope, such as `scrollStarted` and `duration`. While there is nothing "wrong" with your solution, I was hoping for a more closed-scope implementation (if possible). Perhaps there is a way to use only one event (instead of two) or maybe callbacks?

Comment: Put them on `this` the same way you with your interval id. The `let` keyword would bind the other variables to the block they are declared in.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Okay, well that's not quite the same as the global scope then. I don't think there's a way to do what you are looking for, every solution needs to access the timestamp from the `_feedbackScroll` method and you can't expose it without some form of shared variable.

Comment: Yeah I was considering something like a callback to run when the `mouseDown` would finish, and pass the variable that way. But I'm okay with this solution too. cheers.